# Use the page title as the screenshot file name in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

The following PhantomJS code can be used to obtain page title `<title>` of a web page

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function(status) {
    var title = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.title;
    });
    console.log('Page title is ' + title);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

The following PhantomJS code renders multiple URLs to png files.

```
    // Render Multiple URLs to file

    var RenderUrlsToFile, arrayOfUrls, system;

    system = require("system");

    /*
    Render given urls
    @param array of URLs to render
    @param callbackPerUrl Function called after finishing each URL, including the last URL
    @param callbackFinal Function called after finishing everything
    */
    RenderUrlsToFile = function(urls, callbackPerUrl, callbackFinal) {
    var getFilename, next, page, retrieve, urlIndex, webpage;
    urlIndex = 0;
    webpage = require("webpage");
    page = null;
    getFilename = function() {
        return "rendermulti-" + urlIndex + ".png";
    };
    next = function(status, url, file) {
        page.close();
        callbackPerUrl(status, url, file);
        return retrieve();
    };
    retrieve = function() {
        var url;
        if (urls.length > 0) {
            url = urls.shift();
            urlIndex++;
            page = webpage.create();
            page.viewportSize = {
                width: 800,
                height: 600
            };
            page.settings.userAgent = "Phantom.js bot";
            return page.open("http://" + url, function(status) {
                var file;
                file = getFilename();
                if (status === "success") {
                    return window.setTimeout((function() {
                        page.render(file);
                        return next(status, url, file);
                    }), 200);
                } else {
                    return next(status, url, file);
                }
            });
        } else {
            return callbackFinal();
        }
    };
    return retrieve();
    };

    arrayOfUrls = null;

    if (system.args.length > 1) {
        arrayOfUrls = Array.prototype.slice.call(system.args, 1);
    } else {
        console.log("Usage: phantomjs render_multi_url.js [domain.name1, domain.name2, ...]");
        arrayOfUrls = ["www.google.com", "www.bbc.co.uk", "www.phantomjs.org"];
    }

    RenderUrlsToFile(arrayOfUrls, (function(status, url, file) {
        if (status !== "success") {
            return console.log("Unable to render '" + url + "'");
        } else {
            return console.log("Rendered '" + url + "' at '" + file + "'");
        }
    }), function() {
        return phantom.exit();
    });
```

The names of rendered files are in the format of "rendermulti-" + urlIndex + ".png" . But I want it to be page title+".png".  How can I modify above code for my requirement.

Comment: Why did you rollback the edit? An ordered list isn't the correct thing to use here, because those things are not at all equal. What was the problem with the other fixes?

Comment: I really dont know. I did not do it purposely. I did not see option to accept edits or rollback

Comment: Users with at least 2000 reputation can edit any post without review. It means that you cannot approve my edits and only roll them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `page` is global, you can easily change `getFilename()` in this way:

```
getFilename = function() {
    var title = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.title;
    });
    return title + ".png";
};
```

You also don't need to access the page context (inside of `page.evaluate()`) to get the title. You can simply access [`page.title`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/title.html):

```
getFilename = function() {
    return page.title + ".png";
};
```

It may be the case that the title contains characters that cannot appear in a directory or file. If it contains for example `a/b`, this will try write file b.png to directory a which of course doesn't exist.

Simply remove such characters:

```
return title.replace(/[\\\/:]/g, "_") + ".png";
```

Comment: I tried both of above options. But I am not getting what I want. I am using windows 7.
.
Following is the URL list i tried to convert in to pdf.

`code`
    arrayOfUrls = [
'https://app.1doc.com.br/?pg=doc/ver&s=pmsj&authk=8DY98DU918UD1982UWHFFNH&hash=182464F954F1D2C073FAE081&itd=2',
'https://app.1doc.com.br/?pg=doc/ver&s=pmsj&authk=8DY98DU918UD1982UWHFFNH&hash=993FD4A89697BFBC7EEC57E2&itd=1',
'https://app.1doc.com.br/?pg=doc/ver&s=pmsj&authk=8DY98DU918UD1982UWHFFNH&hash=AD47A0AEE180B59B2C54FC14&itd=1' 
];
`code`

Comment: Well, what do you get?

Comment: It dont produce anything. Program is stucked and even after 1 hour execution not finished and no single file is rendered.

Comment: Strange, I'll try it later. What PhantomJS version are you using?

Comment: It is phantomjs-2.0.0-windows.
Here is my code [ https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByBFH5mADm2ubVQwd3ZKU1EyUTQ/view?usp=sharing ]

(sorry about uploading to google. I am not still very clear about stackexchange code formatting)

Comment: You introduced two problems into your code that weren't there before: (1) In line 10 is a syntax error. `webpage,;` should be `webpage;`. (2) If you want to have a protocol for every URL in `arrayOfUrls` then you need to remove the `"http" +` code in the line `return page.open("http://" + url, function(status) {`. Then it will work.

Comment: Made the changes. But it creating folders with the name of page title and not files as intended.
.
Here is a rendering code for single page. [ http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html ]
.
Will it be possible to enhance above code to render multiple pages without much complex code

Comment: Are you sure that the titles don't contain slashes? If they do you need to replace them. Secondly, I don't think this is very complex, but it would be possible to write it slightly shorter.

Comment: Yes Page titles contain slashes. So what to do ?
.
Titles are like this . 
<title>Circular e-001/2013 | Prefeitura de São José | 1Doc</title>
.
I tried following code portion. But still it making folders rather than files.
>
file = getFilename();
file.replace('/', '-')

Comment: `replace` returns the new string but doesn't change the old one. I've updated my answer.